# window-size not working in headless chrome in protractor inside docker but works in local

Tags: docker, protractor, selenium-chromedriver, alpine-linux, google-chrome-headless

**Issue :** window-size in chrome option not working in headless chrome in protractor running inside docker.

**Setup:**

chromedriver version : 2.33 as used by protractor 5.3.1

**Dockerfile :**

```
FROM node:9-alpine

RUN echo @edge http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community >> /etc/apk/repositories \
    && apk add --no-cache \
    python \
    build-base \
    git \
    bash \
    openjdk8-jre-base \
    # chromium dependencies
    nss@edge \
    chromium-chromedriver@edge \
    chromium@edge
```

**Protractor.conf.js :**

```
chromeDriver: '/usr/bin/chromedriver',
directConnect: true,

capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
       args: ['no-sandbox','headless','window-size=1366,768'],
```

***Same setting works in local without docker environment.***

**Error :** Chrome opens up but testcase fail (doesnt attempt to reach app url)

```
 UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: WebDriverError: no such session
```

Tried 1:

```
'window-size=1366,768'
'window-size=1366x768'
'--window-size=1366x768'
'screen-size=1366x768'
```

Tried 2 :

```
 onPrepare: function () {

         browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(1280, 1440);
}
```

This also dint workout with chrome opening in default window size.

Tried 3 :

tried updating protractor to protractor@5.3.1 (was at 5.1) and using

```
'goog:chroomeOptions' : {
   args: ['no-sandbox','headless','window-size=1366,768'],
}
```

Can someone point out whats issue . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a memory issue .

```
--shm-size=1gb
```

resolved it .

Thanks to @sylvaindumont for providing the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `--start-maximized` chrome options in `chromeoptions`. I have this problem once and adding this flag resolved this problem.

Comment: As per my understanding start-maximized is not applicable in case of headless mode . Anyways i tried and it dint worked out . Thanks .